# Correct syntax when printing a object property when using array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the correct syntax when extracting an object property from an array?

example

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
}

var contact = [bob, mary];

console.log(contact[1.phoneNumber]); // <-- Need help here to print phoneNumber!
```

So when I want to print out the phoneNumber property from mary object using the contact array what is the correct syntax?

Comment: `contact[0].phoneNumber`, `contact[1].phoneNumber`? Have you researched this? Searched on Google and similar?

Comment: `console.log( contact[0].phoneNumber ); // will print bob's phone #`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(contact[1.phoneNumber]);` will lead to an Unexpected token ILLEGAL cause there is not such number.

Try this instead:

```
console.log(contact[1].phoneNumber);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2XYc6/)

Comment: @S4M1R maybe you want to get BOB's number?

Comment: laaposto is right, you need `contact[0]` not `contact[1]`

Comment: *"cause there is not such index in array."* no, that wouldn't lead to a syntax error. Accessing a non-existing property simply returns `undefined`. The reason for the error is that `1.x` is invalid if x is not a digit.

Comment: you mean it's the same as array[undefined]?